# R: Extracting year and month from a numeric date

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I have dates in Numeric mode like this:
20/05/2012

What's the most elegant way to extract the year and month from this?

Comment: Possibly with `lubridate`, e.g. `lubridate::month(lubridate::dmy("20/05/2012"))` and `lubridate::year(lubridate::dmy("20/05/2012"))`.

Comment: If you need names weekdays(as.Date("20/05/2012",  format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
[1] "Sunday"  months(as.Date("20/05/2012",  format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
[1] "May"

Answer (score 3):

First you need to convert it to a date object:

```
x <- as.Date("20/05/2012", format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Then to get the month number:

```
format(x,"%m")
```

And to get the year number:

```
format(x,"%Y")
```

If you want the month name (note, this is in your machine language):

```
months(x)
```